# Too many redirects error when deploying with Azure-AD (infinite redirect loop)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, azure-active-directory

I am in the process of adding Azure-AD integration to an MVC web app. When I run it locally everything is working fine, I can log in, log out and the application functions as expected. However, when I deploy (AWS) and try to access the page I get the following error:

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I have tried tracing the redirects and it seems that whatever page I go to it redirects (302) to itself in a loop. The login page is never reached and I am unable to access any page even when they are marked to allow anonymous access.

I am already using the `app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();` fix that is recommended elsewhere but that has had no effect. Any advice would be appreciated.

Per request, this is the authentication code in `Startup.Auth.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                        SetUserInfoCookie(context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Name);
                        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));

                        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                        code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }

                }
        });
}
```

This is the code which calls the authentication when a user clicks on a button. This works as expected when locally, but I am never able to get to the page to run this code after deployment:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
private ActionResult SignInWithAzureAd(string returnUrl)
{
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge();

        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
                .Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }

        return null;
}
```

Comment: These have often been quite hard to debug.. Sometimes it can be the result of having authentication required across the app, and since the response from AAD is not yet authenticated, it redirects it again. Sometimes it has been because it rejects the nonce cookie (which is what that middleware you mention helps for). Anyway, one of these things is happening: 1) The response from AAD can't get through authorization, or 2) The response gets somehow rejected by the OIDC middleware and no user identity is created. See if you can plug in to some of the events OIDC middleware provides.

Comment: Also, could you add the code where you add all the authentication stuff?